# Updating values in pandas group object columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

for key in grouped.groups.keys():

```
    for row in grouped.get_group(key).itertuples():

        if count>0:

            if grouped.get_group(key)['ImpVOL'].values[count] < grouped.get_group(key)['ImpVOL'].values[count-1] :
                #print 'T'
                print 'old_price ', grouped.get_group(key)['SETTLE_PR_2'].values[count]
                print 'old_vol ', grouped.get_group(key)['ImpVOL'].values[count]
                grouped.get_group(key)['SETTLE_PR_2'].values[count] = max(bsm.black_scholes_merton(grouped.get_group(key)['flag'].values[count],
                                                                                    grouped.get_group(key)['FutureClose'].values[count],
                                                                                    grouped.get_group(key)['STRIKE_PR'].values[count],
                                                                                    grouped.get_group(key)['DaysToExpiry'].values[count]/365.0,
                                                                                    r, grouped.get_group(key)['ImpVOL'].values[count-1], q ), 0.05)
                grouped.get_group(key)['ImpVOL'].values[count] =  IV(grouped.get_group(key)['SETTLE_PR_2'].values[count],
                                                                                    grouped.get_group(key)['FutureClose'].values[count],
                                                                                    grouped.get_group(key)['STRIKE_PR'].values[count],
                                                                                    grouped.get_group(key)['DaysToExpiry'].values[count]/365.0,r,q,
                                                                                    grouped.get_group(key)['flag'].values[count])
```

So I wanted to update the values in the groupby object however the above method does not make any changes to the dataframe. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @CSquare So I have a dataframe with 35 columns, 4 out of which I am using for grouping. Then I am performing a nested loop operation, the outer loop is on groups and the inner one is on group rows. Now I want to update values lets say of a particular column dynamically, ie. I want to do some comparison between consecutive rows of that column and keep on updating. It would have been trivial if I was dealing with numpy arrays however here I am not being able to update the values with the above method. Its only creating an instance of the value but not the actual object.

Comment: @CSquare so I am not sure even its feasible to do what I am trying to implement but there must be some workaround i believe. Let me know if you need some more clarification. Because of the size of the dataframe it would be very clumsy if I put it up over here.

Comment: @CSquare so I want that the values of the ImpVol column to be updated when I am assigning it